# Android: Expandable List/Gridview causing never-ending loading

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, android-gridview, expandablelistadapter

My app contains two ExpandableHeightListViews and one ExpandableHeightGridView with shared vertical scrolling.

The contents of the views are read in from a file. This works fine with small files, the data is displayed correctly and the activity loads.

However, when selecting large files, the activity never actually loads, when I debug it, the adapters for the three views are just looping round endlessly. I'm assuming this is due to the expanded nature of the views they are trying to load everything, but surely this can be avoided?

Here is the code ...

ExpandableHeightListView ...

```
public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView
{

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() 
    {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // HACK!  TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded())
        {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) 
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

ExpandableHeightGridView ...

```
public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView
{

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                    int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded()
    {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded())
        {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

MainActivity ...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_editor);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    m_File = new File (intent.getStringExtra ("file_path"));
    m_FileLength = (int) m_File.length();

    // Account for non-complete line at end of file ...
    if ((m_FileLength % 8) == 0)
        m_NumLines = (m_FileLength / 8) + ADDITIONAL_LINES;
    else
        m_NumLines = (m_FileLength / 8) + ADDITIONAL_LINES + 1;

    // Set up index ListView
    m_IndexListView = (ExpandableHeightListView) findViewById (R.id.index_listview);
    m_IndexAdapter = new IndexAdapter (getApplicationContext(), m_NumLines);
    m_IndexListView.setAdapter  (m_IndexAdapter);
    m_IndexListView.setExpanded(true);

    // File reader object for hex/ascii adapters ...
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader (getApplicationContext(), m_File);

    // Set up hex GridView
    m_HexGridView = (ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById (R.id.hex_gridview);
    m_HexAdapter = new HexAdapter (getApplicationContext(), fileReader);
    m_HexGridView.setAdapter(m_HexAdapter);
    m_HexGridView.setExpanded (true);

    // Set up ascii ListView
    m_AsciiListView = (ExpandableHeightListView) findViewById (R.id.ascii_listview);
    m_AsciiAdapter = new AsciiAdapter (getApplicationContext(), m_NumLines, fileReader);
    m_AsciiListView.setAdapter(m_AsciiAdapter);
    m_AsciiListView.setExpanded (true);

    m_HexGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            view.setSelected (true);
        }
    });
```

The three adapters simply read some data from the given file and display it accordingly.

Does anyone know how to fix this and make the adapter views only load the necessary part?

EDIT: Adapter code ...

HexAdapter ...

```
public class HexAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    // CONSTANTS

    // Number of additional blank lines to append ...
    private final int ADDITIONAL_LINES = 30;

    // VARIABLES

    // Context of the EditorActivity ...
    private Context m_Context;
    // Reference to file being edited ...
    private FileReader m_FileReader;
    // Number of elements that are within file ...
    private int m_FileLength;
    // Number of total elements to produce ...
    private int m_NumElements;

    // FUNCTIONS

    public HexAdapter (Context c, FileReader fileReader)
    {
        m_Context    = c;
        m_FileReader = fileReader;
        m_FileLength = (int) m_FileReader.getLength();

        int finishLine = 8 - (m_FileLength % 8);
        m_NumElements = m_FileLength + finishLine + (ADDITIONAL_LINES * 8);
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return m_NumElements;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // Create new TextView for each item referenced by the Adapter ...
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                m_Context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view;
        if (null == convertView)
            view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.editor_hex_element, parent, false);
        else
            view = convertView;

        // Remove padding if rightmost element ...
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById (R.id.gridview_hex_container);
        if ((position % 8) == 7)
            container.setPadding (0,0,0,0);
        else
            container.setPadding (0,0,1,0);

        String hexText;

        // If position is within current file space, read from file ...
        if (position < m_FileLength)
        {
            // Read from file and generate hexadecimal text
            byte[] buffer = m_FileReader.ReadBytesFromFile(position, 1);
            hexText       = Integer.toHexString ((char)buffer[0]).toUpperCase();

            // Prepend extra zero if length is 1 ...
            if (hexText.length() == 1)
                hexText = "0" + hexText;
        }
        else
        {
            // Set to default un-edited value (00) ...
            hexText = "00";
        }

        // Get TextView instance and set text ...
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.gridview_hex_edit);
        textView.setText (hexText);

        // Set colour depending on file length ...
        if (position < m_FileLength)
            textView.setTextColor (m_Context.getResources ().getColor (R.color.DarkerAccentOrange));
        else
            textView.setTextColor (m_Context.getResources ().getColor (R.color.hex_gray));

        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Add function to update file length and numElements variables
    // public void UpdateFileLength (int numLength) ...


}
```

AsciiAdapter ...

```
    public AsciiAdapter (Context c, int numLines, FileReader fileReader)
    {
        m_Context    = c;
        m_FileReader = fileReader;
        m_NumLines   = numLines;
        m_FileLength = (int) fileReader.getLength();
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return m_NumLines;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // Create new TextView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                m_Context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view;
        if (null == convertView)
            view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.editor_ascii_element, parent, false);
        else
            view = convertView;

        final int readPosition  = position * BYTE_SIZE;
        final int fileRemaining = m_FileLength - readPosition;
        final int readLength    = (fileRemaining >= BYTE_SIZE) ? BYTE_SIZE : fileRemaining;

        byte[] buffer;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder ();

        // If some of file remaining, read ...
        if (readLength > 0)
        {
            buffer = m_FileReader.ReadBytesFromFile (readPosition, readLength);
            // Build read string ...
            for (byte b : buffer)
                builder.append (convertByte (b));
        }

        // Append remaining part of string (not read from file) ...
        final int remaining = (readLength > 0) ? (BYTE_SIZE - readLength) : BYTE_SIZE;
        for (int k = 0; k < remaining; k++)
            builder.append ('.');

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.ascii_textview);
        textView.setText (builder.toString());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to show the code for the loading of the file.  That is most likely the cause

Comment: Does this code work with "normal" `ListView` and `GridView`s? If so, that may be a hint and maybe there's something wrong with `// HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!`.

Comment: It does work with normal list/gridviews without the shared scrolling, I assumed it would be a problem with that class (not sure if the thread I got it from was supposed to be used like this), was more hoping someone had seen a way around it before

Comment: Or a working way of sharing scrolling between the three standard adapterviews without the need for their ExpandableHeight edits ...

Comment: I have added the code for the adapters above if that helps any...